# State machine controlling dc motor/ buzzer/ lcd / ultrasonic

Tags: programming

I ran into some problems here with programming. I am trying to put together a code for 4dc motors, buzzer, ultrasonic and lcd to work together,. they will together make up a small car. when the distance to the ultrasonic is smaller than 10cm, the buzzer makes a random sound, and a funny face. Meanwhile the motors will stop for 2 seconds, goes back for 2 seconds and do a turning motion for 8 seconds. However. I do not want to use the delay function for the motors since it will cause the buzzer to sound too slowly. I was directed from an earlier thread that I should use a state machine,but when I tried to put the motor controls in, my motors does not turn, can someone help me with spotting what is the problem here?
Thank you!

```
#define HALT_TIME 2000
#define BACK_TIME 2000
#define TURN_TIME 8000
#define trigPin A1
#define echoPin A0
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <NewTone.h>
#include<AFMotor.h>

long duration;
int distance;
int distanceUltra;
int maximum = 100;
int buzzerPin = A2;
int dur = 100;

LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 7, 12, 13);
AF_DCMotor motor1(1,MOTOR34_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2,MOTOR34_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor3(3,MOTOR34_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor4(4,MOTOR34_1KHZ);

enum ApplicationState {
  BeginDrive,
  Drive,
  BeginHalt,
  Halt,
  BeginBack,
  Back,
  BeginTurn,
  Turn
};

static enum ApplicationState currentApplicationState = BeginDrive;

static unsigned long t = 0;

static bool sensorTriggered() {
  
  if (distance <= 10){return true;}
  
  else {return false;}
}

static void funnyFace() {

    lcd.setCursor(6,0);
    lcd.write("x");
    lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    lcd.write("x");
    lcd.setCursor(7,1);
    lcd.write("o");
    randSound(maximum);//random sound for buzzer
}

static void beginDriveHandler() {
    Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
    
    motor1.setSpeed(100);
    motor1.run(BACKWARD);
    motor2.setSpeed(100);
    motor2.run(BACKWARD);
    motor3.setSpeed(100);
    motor3.run(BACKWARD);
    motor4.setSpeed(100);
    motor4.run(BACKWARD);
  currentApplicationState = Drive;
  
}

static void driveHandler() {
  
  if (sensorTriggered()) {
    Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
    t = millis();
    currentApplicationState = BeginHalt;
  }
}

static void beginHaltHandler() {
  Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
    motor1.setSpeed(0);
    motor1.run(RELEASE);
    motor2.setSpeed(0);
    motor2.run(RELEASE);
    motor3.setSpeed(0);
    motor3.run(RELEASE);
    motor4.setSpeed(0);
    motor4.run(RELEASE);
 
  funnyFace();
  currentApplicationState = Halt;
}

static void haltHandler() {
  
  if (millis() - t > HALT_TIME) {
    Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
    t = millis();
    currentApplicationState = BeginBack;
  }
}

static void beginBackHandler() {
Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
    motor1.setSpeed(100);
    motor1.run(FORWARD);
    motor2.setSpeed(100);
    motor2.run(FORWARD);
    motor3.setSpeed(100);
    motor3.run(FORWARD);
    motor4.setSpeed(100);
    motor4.run(FORWARD);
  currentApplicationState = Back;
}

static void backHandler() {
  
  if (millis() - t > BACK_TIME) {
    Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
    t = millis();
    currentApplicationState = BeginTurn;
  }
}

static void beginTurnHandler() {
Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
    motor1.setSpeed(100);
    motor1.run(FORWARD);
    motor2.setSpeed(100);
    motor2.run(FORWARD);
    motor3.setSpeed(100);
    motor3.run(BACKWARD);
    motor4.setSpeed(100);
    motor4.run(BACKWARD);
  currentApplicationState = Turn;
}

static void turnHandler() {
  
  if (millis() - t > TURN_TIME) {
    Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
    currentApplicationState = BeginDrive;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  pinMode (trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  //Serial.println(sensorTriggered());
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration*0.034/2;
  switch (currentApplicationState) {

    case BeginDrive:
    beginDriveHandler();
    break;
    
    case Drive:
    driveHandler();
    break;

    case BeginHalt:
    beginHaltHandler();
    break;

    case Halt:
    haltHandler();
    break;

    case BeginBack:
    beginBackHandler();
    break;

    case Back:
    backHandler();
    break;

    case BeginTurn:
    beginTurnHandler();
    break;

    case Turn:
    turnHandler();
    break;
  }

  //Serial.println(currentApplicationState);
}


void randSound(int maximum){
  NewTone(buzzerPin, random(maximum, 10*maximum),dur);
  delay(maximum);
  noNewTone(buzzerPin);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are really using a [9 volt battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery) you are very likely under powering your project.  While the voltage may work, the amount of current such a battery can produce is likely way below what your project needs to operate as expected.

Comment: Those little yellow gearmotors are typically around 200mA each with no load. You'd be far better off powering at least the motors w/ a bank of AAs.

Comment: You need to set `t` to `millis()` before reaching the handler with the if millis statement, so in the `Begin...` Handlers. Otherwise most likely `t` has such an old value, that the state will change immediately.

Comment: start motors and store the value of millis() for the 2 second timer in `beginDriveHandler` ... watch the time and sensor in `driveHandler`